# Reactive Angular Material Data Table

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

I've created an Angular Material Data Table with this `ng generate @angular/material:material-table` command and it gave me following file structure:

- **table-datasource.ts**
- **table.component.ts**
- **table.component.html**

The idea here is to do all the fetching, sorting and pagination in the `table-datasource.ts`. By default the data is placed in an Array inside `table-datasource.ts` but in my case its coming from an ngxs-store which exposes an **Observable of an Array**. Atm I have following implementation:

**table-datasource.ts:**

```
export class TokenTableDataSource extends DataSource<TokenTableItem> {
  @Select(TokenTableState.getTokenTableItems) private tokenTableItems$:Observable<TokenTableItem[]>;
  totalItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<TokenTableItem[]>([]);

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  /**
  * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
  * the returned stream emits new items.
  * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
  */
  connect(): Observable<TokenTableItem[]> {
    this.tokenTableItems$.subscribe(item => this.totalItems$.next(item));

    // init on first connect
    if (this.totalItems$.value === undefined) {
      this.totalItems$.next([]);
      this.paginator.length = this.totalItems$.value.length;
    }
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.totalItems$),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(
      map(() =>  this.totalItems$.next(this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.totalItems$.value])))),
      mergeMap(() => this.totalItems$)
    );
  }
  ...generated paging and sorting methods
```

**table-component.html:**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">

  ...multiple columns

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="this.dataSource.totalItems$.value?.length"
      [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      [showFirstLastButtons]=true
      (page)="handlePage($event)">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**table.component.ts:**

```
export class TokenTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: TokenTableDataSource;

  pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 20, 40];
  pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
  pageIndex = 0;
  tableLength = 0;

  ... colums definition

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new TokenTableDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
  }

  public handlePage(pageEvent: PageEvent) {
    // do what?
  }
}
```

**What's working:**

- The data is rendered correct (triggered with a button and via the ngxs-store)
- I can sort the data

**What's not working:**

- On first data load the pageSize is ignored at all and all rows are displyed
- When clicking sorting or a pagination element, the current selected `pageSize` is taken and this amount of rows is rendered. What's strange to me is that this only works descending (given `pageSize` is 10 and I select 5 it results in 5 rows but once 5 is selected it's not possible to display more rows than 5 again)

**Requirements:**

- I like the idea to encapsulate all data manipulations behind `TableDataSource.connect()` so a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318164/how-to-use-paginator-from-material-angular) where the fetching is done in the comonent is not desired. Furthermore this doesn't have sorting implemented.
- The app uses an **ngxs-store**, which is very similar to **ngrx**, so any solution involving this part is welcome.
- I haven't figured out what to do with **pageEvents** so my guess is that the solution is in the `handlePage()` method.

**Versions:**

- RxJS 6.3.x
- Angular 7.x
- ngxs 3.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to setup a table for my requirements. The main change is that I removed the Observable which fetches the data from the **TableDataSource** and introduced a **DataService**:

```
export class DataService {
  //the @Select is from ngxs but can be anything returning an Observable 
  @Select(TokenTableState.getTokenTableItems) private tokenTableItems$: Observable<TokenTableViewItem[]>;
  private initValue$: BehaviorSubject<TokenTableViewItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject<TokenTableViewItem[]>([]);

  getAllItems(): Observable<TokenTableViewItem[]> {
    const sources = [this.tokenTableItems$, this.initValue$];
    return merge(...sources);
  }
}
```

Basically that service gets the data from any Observable input and merges this in the **getAllItems** method with an initial value.

The **Component** has an instance of this service:

`private _dataService: DataService | null;`

which it hands over to the **TableDatasource** in the load method:

```
private loadData(): any {
    this._dataService = new DataService();
    this.dataSource = new TokenTableDataSource(
      this._dataService,
      this.paginator,
      this.sort
    );
    fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup').subscribe(() => {
      if (!this.dataSource) {
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
    });
  }
```

The reason I don't have a reference of the **DataService** in the **TableDataSource** is that the paginator in the **Component** needs the length of the table for rendering (seen below).

The **TableDataSource** consumes the **DataService** like this:

- In the **connect** method it holds an array with possible data mutations:

  ```
  const dataMutations = [
    this._dataChange,
    this._sort.sortChange,
    this._filterChange,
    this._paginator.page
  ];
  ```
- The **_dataChange** member of the array gets it value by subscribing to the **getAllItems** method from our **DataService**:

  ```
  this._internalService.getAllItems().subscribe(data => {
    this._dataChange.next(data);
  });
  ```
- The **dataMutations** are used like this to filter, sort and return the data which should be displayed:

  ```
  return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(
    map(() => {
      // Filter data
      this.filteredData = this._dataChange.value
        .slice()
        .filter((item: TokenTableViewItem) => {
          const searchStr = (item.symbol + item.name).toLowerCase();
          return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
      // Sort filtered data
      const sortedData = this.getSortedData(this.filteredData.slice());

      // Grab the page's slice of the filtered sorted data.
      this.renderedData = this.getPagedData(sortedData);
      return this.renderedData;
    })
  );
  ```

The **filterChange** is defined in the local instance

`_filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');`

while the **pagination** and **sorting** are triggered from outside via the constructor

```
constructor(
  public _internalService: DataService,
  public _paginator: MatPaginator,
  public _sort: MatSort
) {
  super();
  this._filterChange.subscribe(() => (this._paginator.pageIndex = 0));
}
```

I also found a solution for the pagination which is defined in the **component.html** like this:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
  [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length"
  [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
  [showFirstLastButtons]=true>
</mat-paginator>
```

and with the variables set in the **component.ts**:

```
pageSizeOptions = [5, 10, 20, 40];
pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
pageIndex = 0;
```

The full code can be seen at [this](https://github.com/BernhardFuchs/whatsmytokens/tree/master/src/app/dapp-dashboard/token-table) project and a live version of the table is used at [whatsmytoken.com](https://whatsmytokens.com/).

Answer (score 0):

WOW!
just about the same time, I wrote an article about my Reactive DataSource, that can be easily extended for multiple data lists! you can add *optional* and *required* **mutators**, accompanied of **getter** functions to collect the respective arguments and merge them in a REQuest object.

I explained the overall stuff here:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6

and I mounted a demo on StackBlitz too
with a Github repo showing with simple commits,
how simple is to set up a filtered/sorted/paginated list in a clean way.

I hope you give me some feedback about my library,
and if you find it appealing, I can be sure to support you with your use cases too :)

Happy coding!